# Dependency issues while using one gradle project in another

Tags: java, gradle

I am new to Gradle, basically from Maven background.

I have the following dependency in one project [Lets call it **'Project A'**]

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
```

Now I want to use **'Project A'** in **'Project B'**. I have done the following to refer Project A in Project B.

Updated the `settings.gradle` of **Project B** to include **Project A**

```
include ':project-a' 
project(':project-a').projectDir = new File('path to Project A')
```

Following is added to  **Project B** `build.gradle`

```
implementation project(":project-a")
```

While synchronizing, **Project B** complains the following.

> Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution
> 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip'.
> Build file 'path to project A\build.gradle' line: 9 A problem occurred
> evaluating project ':project-a'. Could not find method
> implementation() for arguments [{group=org.apache.commons,
> name=commons-lang3, version=3.0}] on object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

************************UPDATE*************************
Java plugin added as requested in comment

```
apply plugin: 'java'

//plugins {
//  id 'java'
//}


dependencies {
    
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework',       name: 'spring-context',    version: "${spring_version}"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot',  name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure',    version: "${springboot_version}"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-context'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-commons'
```

**versions** are declared in gradle.properties file

```
spring_version=5.2.5.RELEASE
springboot_version=2.2.6.RELEASE
servlet_version=3.1.0
```

Now none of the dependencies are getting downloaded.

Comment: Could you add more parts of your `build.gradle` files? Which plugins are applied to your projects? In order to add dependencies to the `implementation` configuration, the `java` plugin needs to be applied.